# POJO as a BeaconConsumer instead of Activity

Tags: ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, altbeacon

I am trying to use a POJO as a BeaconConsumer. Is this acceptable? The onServiceConnect is getting called. But I have to forcefully override the unbindService and the bindService.

Comment: Can you please include sample code of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the BeaconConsumer interface is designed to work with an Activity, Service or Application instance.  There's nothing wrong using a POJO as a BeaconConsumer, but it must hold a reference to the Context.  The POJO's bindService and unbindService methods must be chained to the equivalent methods on the Context like this:

```
@Override
public boolean bindService(Intent intent, ServiceConnection conn, int mode) {
    return context.bindService(intent, conn, mode);
}

@Override
public void unbindService(ServiceConnection conn) {
    context.unbindService(conn);
}
```

Also, take care that something long-living in the Android lifecycle (an Activity, Application, etc.) holds a reference to the POJO so it doesn't get garbage collected of during the Android lifecycle.